# Convergence of eigenvectors and eigenvalues of matrix that converges

Tags: matrix, convergence, eigenvalues, matrix-decomposition, random-matrix

For each random variable $X=x$, there is a symmetric positive definite matrix $M(x)$. Suppose there is a set of samples of random matrix $M_1,M_2,...,M_n$, where each $M_i$ is calculated based on the associated random sample $X=x_i$. Let $\hat{M}_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n M_i$, there is the convergence result that $\hat{M}_n\rightarrow E[M]$ at some rate relating to $n$, i.e. $\hat{M}_n-E[M]=O_p(\epsilon_n)$, where the convergence rate $\epsilon_n$ depends on the sample size $n$.

Suppose we have eigen-decomposition for the two matrices that $\hat{M}_n=\hat{V}_n\hat{\Lambda}_n\hat{V}_n^{T}$ and $E[M]=V\Lambda V^{T}$, may I ask whether there are some convergence relationship between $\hat{V}_n$, $\hat{\Lambda}_n$ and $V$, $\Lambda$ respectively?

Many thanks!

Comment: Not sure I understand how convergence rate may depend on sample size. I understand that the discrepancy itself depends on the sample size, but the rate should be an unambiguous function of $n$... be it $n^{-1/2}$ or $n \log(\log(n))$ or $n^{-3/7} \log^{1/2} n$.

Answer (score 1):

Jan Magnus has his book on matrix calculus available [online](http://www.janmagnus.nl/misc/mdc2007-3rdedition). Section 8.7, page 177 and on, deals with differentials in eigenproblems. See if you can apply the delta method and carry through the big $O$ and small $o$ through those differentials. Without knowing your convergence rates, though, I don't really know if your question could be answered. He discusses the various pathological situations that have to deal with multiple eigenvalues, so if you have something converging say to $\lambda=1$ at different rates, you may have something real weird in your eigenvalues.

In a situation when all eigenvalues are 1, there exist a non-degenerate asymptotic distribution of sample eigenvalues, see e.g. [Johnstone (2001)](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1009210544) or the original probability theory literature (Marcenko-Pastur semicircle law) he cites. You are probably familiar with that literature, and if that stuff is relevant, this could be indicated in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The Davis-Kahan theorem might help you. You can have a look on it and its application there: [spectral clustering tutorial](http://www.kyb.mpg.de/fileadmin/user_upload/files/publications/attachments/luxburg06_TR_v2_4139%5B1%5D.pdf) in the "perturbation theory point of view" paragraph.